# How to format long SQL Query in SSMS to make it look more organized?

Tags: sql, format

I am wondering if there is a way in SSMS to somehow format a list of code to make it more neat.

For example, right now it looks similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (
 'Test'
,'Value'
,'Random'
,'Hello'
,'Testing'
,'Hi'
,'SQL'
,'SSMS'
,'Table'
,'Column'
,...
,...

)
```

And this goes on for hundreds of lines, since I copied and pasted the values from another query into the IN statement. I was wondering if there was a way to somehow auto format the long list of values into a more "block" like format?

Something more like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (
'Test','Value','Random','Hello','Testing',
'Hi','SQL','SSMS','Table','Column',
...,...,...
)
```

Comment: If it is a sequence of continuous numbers, then you can use BETWEEN AND operator.. or if in groups, you can use >=,<= etc

Comment: It isn't a sequence of continuous numbers, I just used that as an example so the BETWEEN wouldn't work in this case. I just updated the code to reflect more so of the randomness of the values.

Comment: So when you say that you copied and pasted values from another query, so can't you directly use a subquery instead?

Comment: That could work as well, I was not thinking about that. Thank you

Comment: sure, no problem!!